# Select date range from string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have just inherited a database, he inserted all the dates as strings so
the data looks like this

```
19730815 ...... no further comment on that!
```

I need to select everyone who was born in March with the age range of 5 - 15. 
please help me with this t-sql query thanks

```
select * from A1 where DBate = ?????
```

Comment: First thing to do is cleanup the database. Extract the dates into a column of their own of type `Date` (or `DateTime` if before SQL Server 2008).

Comment: In SQL Server, If its a varchar (or char) and its stored as `YYYYMMDD`, then it can be treated as an `DATETIME` without amiguity, so it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: @Lamak - It is _part_ of the VARCHAR, the start of it, apparently.

Comment: @user1264626 - Well, you said on your question "he inserted all the dates as **strings**", but if its an `INT`, you are facing a similar problem. What is your RDBMS by the way?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from A1 where month(convert(datetime, DBate))=3 and (year(getdate)-year(convert(datetime, '20161023'))) between 5 and 15
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `SUBSTRING` function in sql to remove the month and date from the string and compare to find the age and month of birth.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do some string manipulation to create a useable DateTime, that you can then use to perform a DateDiff against the current date, and use a Between clause to filter to a range of these DateDiffs. Maybe something like this:

```
select * 
from A1 
where DBate = DateDiff(yy, 
      Convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(BDate,0,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(BDate,4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(BDate,6,2)), 
   GetDate()) 
   BETWEEN 5 AND 15
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's an int, you have have some fun with the \ and % operators to return the year and month:

```
SELECT *
FROM A1
WHERE
    (DBate/100)%100 = 3
AND
    (YEAR(GETDATE()) - (DBate/10000)) BETWEEN 5 AND 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of datediff() and datepart(). This example is careful to factor in exact dates when figuring ages in years.

```
declare @today datetime; set @today=getdate(); --or declare @today date if SQL 2008+

-- Build some sample data
declare @bds table(id int identity(1,1),bd varchar(8));

insert into @bds values ('19730815') --out of range
, ('20070310') --in range when @today is on or after 3/10/2012
, ('20070315') --out of range when @today is before 3/15/2012
, ('20070801') --out of range
, ('20040305') --in range when @today is on or after 3/05/2012

-- Find ages 5 to 15, born in March
select *
, age=DATEDIFF(yyyy,bd,@today)
    -Case when DATEADD(yyyy,-DATEDIFF(yyyy,bd,@today),@today)>bd then 0 else 1 end
from @bds
where DATEDIFF(yyyy,bd,@today)
    -Case when DATEADD(yyyy,-DATEDIFF(yyyy,bd,@today),@today)>bd then 0 else 1 end
between 5 and 15
and datepart(mm,bd)=3 -- or month(d) in SQL 2008+
```

Result, with @today=3/12/2012:

```
id          bd       age
----------- -------- -----------
2           20070310 5
5           20040305 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE dbo.AgeInYears(dbo.DateFromDigits(DateOfBirth)) BETWEEN 5 AND 15
AND MONTH(dbo.DateFromDigits(DateOfBirth)) = 3
```

The functions `DateFromDigits` and `AgeInYears` are defined here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DateFromDigits(@digits int) RETURNS smalldatetime AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE WHEN ISDATE(CAST(@digits AS char(8))) = 1
            THEN CAST(CAST(@digits AS char(8)) AS smalldatetime)
        END
END

CREATE FUNCTION AgeInYears(@date smalldatetime) RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(YY, @date, GETDATE()) -
            CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                    AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE()))
                    OR MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE())
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END)
END
```